# What changes as a developer need to change in the code base for iOS13 SDK

Tags: ios

Now I am using Xcode 10.1, Does I need to update my Xcode version based on those requirements?
Requirements are->

```
Below are the things apple has sent on mail to cross-verify

Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.

iPhone apps must support all iPhone screens and all iPad apps must support all iPad screens.

Apps for Apple Watch must be built with the watchOS 6 SDK or later.

Apps that authenticate or set up user accounts must support Sign in with Apple if required by guideline 4.8 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apps in the Kids Category must be in full compliance with guideline 1.3 and guideline 5.1.4. of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apps using HTML 5 must be in full compliance with guideline 4.7 sections 4, 5, and 6 of the App Store Review Guidelines.
```

if someone has done do let us know what changes you have done.
Thank you

Comment: To uplaod a new build you must use ios 13 sdk which is available only in xcode 11+. so you need to update xcode to publish or take builds of you project

Comment: Xcode 11 and + version,Xcode 11 can?

Comment: Yes. but uploading to latest version of xcode if possible.

Comment: Okay,thanks for your answer

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar In Xcode 11.4,Does I need to change swift version?Swift 4 is OK to upload?

Comment: No problem with that. swift 4 compiles with xcode11. so no need to upgrade swift version